# Finding attributes .on("click") from unrelated div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have it where pressing `"btn1"` alone populates the sidebar. I tried `$("#container").on("click", ".btn1", function()` but it doesn't work.

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".item", function() {
  $("#title").text($(this).find(".title").text());
  var itemImgSrc = $(this).find(".image").attr("src");
  $("#image")
    .css("background-image", 'url("' + itemImgSrc + '")')
    .css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.image {
  height: 100px;
}
#image {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn1"></button>
    <div class="title">Dog</div>
    <img class="image" src="http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23244_what-is-the-appenzeller-sennenhunde-dog-300x189.jpg">
  </div>
  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <div class="item">
  <button class="btn1"></button>
    <div class="title">Cat</div>
    <img class="image" src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx">
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar Div -->
</div>
  <div class="modal">
    <h2 id="title"></h2>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.title` and `.image` are not contained in `.btn1`. You need to go up to the containing `.item` and then find them.

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".btn1", function() {
  var item = $(this).closest(".item");
  $("#title").text(item.find(".title").text());
  var itemImgSrc = item.find(".image").attr("src");
  $("#image")
    .css("background-image", 'url("' + itemImgSrc + '")')
    .css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.image {
  height: 100px;
}
#image {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn1"></button>
    <div class="title">Dog</div>
    <img class="image" src="http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23244_what-is-the-appenzeller-sennenhunde-dog-300x189.jpg">
  </div>
  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <div class="item">
  <button class="btn1"></button>
    <div class="title">Cat</div>
    <img class="image" src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx">
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar Div -->
</div>
  <div class="modal">
    <h2 id="title"></h2>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </div>
```

You could also use `$(this).siblings(".title')` and `$(this).siblings(".image")`.

Comment: I'm trying to take the string from .link and replace the text string from #link (located in a separate div) when either button is pressed. So #link is a dummy link that gets populated by the .link text when either of the buttons is clicked

Comment: That's even easier, just use `$(".btn1 .link")` as the selector.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with dynamic data. If I set up my code this way, it populates the link, but it doesn't correspond to the link text from the item in my dynamic list. It just gives the first text from all items.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "all items"? `.text()` only gets the text from the first match of the selector. Sounds like you need to post your HTML and show exactly what you intend the result to be, because your descriptions are incomplete.

Comment: Please post code in the question, not codepen. Use [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: And leave out all the irrelevant stuff, post a [mcve] that shows the problem you're having. And you need to explain what the result should be.

Comment: Okay I edited the main post to give a more clear example. I think all I need is to know how to populate the sidebar by pressing ".btn1"

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Working. Thanks for taking the time to look into this for me. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$(this)` to `$(.btn1)`.
`$(this)` being the button clicked works for `.btn1` and not for `.btn2`, changing it from dynamic `$(this)` to always looking for `.link` in `.btn1` should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using  $(this).parent().find(".title"). You could move up the heirarchy and get the element from there and then

```
$("#container").on("click", ".item", function() {
  $("#title").text($(this).parent().find(".title").text());
  var itemImgSrc = $(this).parent().find(".image").attr("src");
  $("#image")
    .css("background-image", 'url("' + itemImgSrc + '")')
    .css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.image {
  height: 100px;
}
#image {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn1"></button>
    <div class="title">Dog</div>
    <img class="image" src="http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23244_what-is-the-appenzeller-sennenhunde-dog-300x189.jpg">
  </div>
  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <div class="item">
  <button class="btn1"></button>
    <div class="title">Cat</div>
    <img class="image" src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx">
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar Div -->
</div>
  <div class="modal">
    <h2 id="title"></h2>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </div>
```

Also try using an index with the find method. it returns an array but i dont think that giving index is necessary when there is only one element.

something like this
$(this).parent().find(".item")[0].text();